# Android flavor and build variant specific appboy.xml file

Tags: android, android-resources, android-build-type, android-flavors, appboy

Regarding an Android app having different flavors and build variants, I'm quite familiar with how to build certain string resources flavor & build variant specific. But for a file I'm not sure how that works.

More concretely, I'm integrating Appboy into my app only for a specific flavor, the api key is different for the different build variants. So how can I manage to do this?

My `appboy.xml` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!--Appboy api key, used in debug and preview builds-->
    <string name="com_appboy_api_key">MY_APPBOY_API_KEY</string>
</resources>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create for each Flavor/build variant a directory and put your Appboy configuration in it:

- Flavor1Debug    : app/src/flavor1Debug/res/values/appboy.xml
- Flavor1Release  :app/src/flavor1Release/res/values/appboy.xml
- Flavor2Debug    :app/src/flavor2Debug/res/values/appboy.xml
- Flavor2Release  :app/src/flavor2Release/res/values/appboy.xml

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect Answer. It is possible to create just one directory app/src/flavor for Debug & Release.